# ¿Cuál es el objetivo de declarar una variable donde su tipo es el nombre de una interfaz?

Tags: java

Quisiera aclarar una duda, tengo el siguiente código que me confunde.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    InterfacePersona alexis = new Persona("Alexis");
    Persona jose = new Persona("Jose");
}
```

Cual es la diferencia entre la primera línea y la segunda? veo en muchos videos que para crear un objeto de una clase ponen el nombre de una interface y no se en realidad que es lo que se logra con eso.

La primera línea es lo que quisiera comprender, y la segunda es lo que siempre implemento y hago en mis proyectos.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: esto es más por el uso de java 8 lo primero es una interfaz funcional aunque está mal implementada( pues debe hacer la implementación del método para hacer un new) y la segunda es la creación de un POJO parece según lo que muestras en tu código. Si agregas el código completo se te puede ayudar un poco más.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, en el minuto 4:58 de este video aplica lo que comento: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dAAB2EqMiC4&list=PLU8oAlHdN5Blq85GIxtKjIXdfHPksV_Hm&index=7 ||

Sin embargo, a pesar que allí en el video lo explica no logro comprenderlo bien.

Comment: Eso se hace para poder trabajar con jerarquías de objetos, de manera que declarando una variable de la clase padre, en esa variable se pueden instanciar objetos de cualquier clase heredera. Ocurre lo mismo con las interfaces.

Comment: @DavElsanto, cómo deduces que `InterfacePersona` es una interfaz funcional y que `Persona` es un POJO?

Answer (score 4):

Lo primero que tenemos que entender que es una interfaz (no GUI) en java. Una interfaz define un contrato que todas las clases que la implementen deben cumplir.

Como bien se explica en el video, el objetivo de este tipo de técnicas de programación es permitirnos utilizar abstracciones las que posibilitan que cuando necesitemos cambiar de implementación no tengamos que modificar el código.

Un ejemplo bien sencillo de entender (eso espero) lo podemos sacar del API Collections. Aquí tenemos una interfaz `List` que define una serie de métodos asociados a la estructura de datos lista. Entre muchas implementaciones que existe para esta interfaz tenemos 2 muy usadas: `ArrayList` y `LinkedList`. Cada una de estas implementaciones nos brindan ventajas y desventajas (como casi todo en la vida y en programación) las cuales nos harán elegir cual es la más adecuada para nuestro problema.

Si tuvieramos este código

```
public Element findElementByCriteria(ArrayList<Element> elements, String criteria) {
    // lógica del método
}
```

Estaríamos forzados a trabajar solo con el tipo de listas `ArrayList` y si en algún punto del desarrollo tengo que trabajar tambien con `LinkedList`, entonces tengo que agregar un nuevo método que reciba una `LinkedList` o modificar este para que la soporte.

Sin dudas la mejor opción es la segunda puesto que me va a evitar este tipo de problemas en un futuro.

```
public Element findElementByCriteria(List<Element> elements, String criteria) {
    // lógica del método
}
```

Este es el tipo de problemas que nos evita el trabajar con abstracciones, pero sobre todo con interfaces, ya que las clases abstractas o las superclases (que son otros tipos de abstracciones) siguen siendo implementaciones. Si usas Spring verás como el uso de interfaces sobre implementaciones concretas es masivo y esto nos posibilita intercambiar componentes de nuestra aplicación sin tener que tocar muchas veces ni una línea de código.